# How to access h2 database after deploying play 2 application with boxfuse

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, h2, cloudcaptain

How can I access my h2 database after deploying a play 2 application with boxfuse?
I've tried 'boxfuse open -db -env=test' but it says it's unable to find the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `boxfuse open -db` is for database instances (MySQL or PostgreSQL) auto-provisioned by Boxfuse (https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/databases).

Your H2 database could have been started in 3 different ways: in-memory, file and tcp server. For in-memory and file there is no way to access it externally (unless your application serves as some kind of gateway). For tcp server you have to expose the DB port to the outside world using something like `-ports.db=9092` which you can then use to connect to using your favorite DB client.